# How to Implement File Upload and Send to External API in Python Flet View?

Tags: python, filepicker, flet

could someone help me with the following?
I'm creating a view where users will be able to upload an audio file, and later, that audio will be sent to an external API.
I'm having trouble understanding the logic of the file picker and how to add it to my view.
Does anyone know how I could apply that to this view?
I'm interested in capturing the audio that the user uploads so I can send it to my external API.
Thank you very much in advance! :)
This is the code from my summary.py file:
`from flet import *
from controls import navbar
from view import ShowMenu

def *view*():
return View(
"/summary",
bgcolor="white54",
controls=[
Column(
expand=True,
controls=[
Row(
expand=True,
controls=[
# Navbar
Column(
alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
controls=[
Container(
margin=-10,
bgcolor="#1d1d1d",
width=60,
expand=True,
animate=animation.Animation(350,"decelerate"),
on_hover=lambda e: ShowMenu(e),
content=navbar.ModernNavbar(
lambda e: None,
lambda e: e.page.go("/profile"),
lambda e: e.page.go("/home"),

```
                                    ),             
                                )    
                            ],
                        ),
                        # Main content
                        VerticalDivider(color='transparent', width=60),
                        Column(
                            expand=True,
                            alignment=MainAxisAlignment.START,
                            horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                            controls=[
                                Divider(color='transparent', height=30),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    "Audio Upload",
                                    icon=icons.FOLDER_OPEN,
                                    on_click=lambda _: None
                                ),
                                Text("File name: ..."),

                                ElevatedButton(
                                    "Start Analysis",
                                    icon=icons.ANALYTICS,
                                    on_click=lambda _: None
                                ),
                               
                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)`
```

Explain what you expected to happen when you attempted those code or approaches. What was your intended outcome?